# Problem in writing correct Zend Query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

> ```
> SELECT `vacancy`.`id`, `vacancy`.`job_title_final` FROM `tableone`
> INNER JOIN `tabletwo` 
> ON tabletwo.client_user_id=tableone.employer
> WHERE (job_title_final LIKE '%expert%') 
> AND ((org_addr_country LIKE '%nepal%') 
>     OR (org_addr_city LIKE '%nepal%') 
>     OR (org_addr_street LIKE '%nepal%'))
> ```

please help me writing the zend subquery of above sql.
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a subquery at all. Unless you're hiding the main query. You also hasn't posted your code as @fb1 said. If you expect good answers, you need to work on it.

Comment: sorry i mistakenly wrote sub query instead of query.....i changed it now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so without a schema list:

```
$value1 = "nepal";
$value2 = "expert";

$select = $db->select()
    ->from(array('one' => 'tableone'),  array('id', 'jop_title_final'))
    ->join(array('two' => 'tabletwo'), 'one.client_user_id = two.employer', array())
    ->where("job_title_final LIKE '%$value2%'")
    ->where("org_addr_country LIKE '%$value1%' OR org_addr_city LIKE '%$value1%' OR org_addr_street LIKE '%$value1%'");
```

I'm making some assumptions, that vacancy.id and vacancy.job_title_final are supposed to come from tabletwo - vacancy table doesn't exist in the context of this query you may want to fix that so your question makes more sense.